# Regarding Fused location Provider in Android to Fetch Location

Tags: android, location

It seems to be a silly question but it might affect the design of application that I m developing .

Fused location providers provides location data in onLocationChanged () callback only when device gps is turned on. So i m confused what's the benefit of using fused location provider if It has such a dependency on device gps ?

Please help to explain

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What's the benefit of using fused location provider if it has such a dependency on device gps ?

**The FusedLocationProvider may or may not use GPS, depending on the accuracy and update interval that you request.** The main benefit is that the FusedLocationProvider conveniently abstracts the process of choosing suitable providers (WiFi, GPS, Network, BLE) and fusing the location info from those providers, hence the name.

The best choice of providers can depend on both the capabilities of the client device as well as your physical surroundings (e.g. WiFi might perform better than GPS in an urban environment with lots of tall buildings, while out in the wilderness it will be the other way round). So unless you need fine-grained control of the location providers I would suggest letting the FusedLocationProvider / the Google API decide.

Regarding application design: I have written a utility class, called the [LocationAssistant](https://github.com/klaasnotfound/LocationAssistant), which will actually handle most of the setup for you. You might find it useful, as you're left with only a few simple interface methods to implement.